# Show $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, solution-verification

> Find the Galois group of $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then show $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My attempt:**

The roots of $x^3-5$ are $\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{5}$. So the splitting field for $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta_3)$, where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive $3^\text{rd}$ root of unity. By the Degree Formula for field extensions, we have
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)][\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=3\varphi(3)=3\cdot2=6,
$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.
Define the automorphisms
$$
\sigma_{ij}:=\begin{cases}
\sqrt[3]{5}&\longmapsto\quad\zeta_3^i\sqrt[3]{5}\\
\zeta_3&\longmapsto\quad\zeta_3^j
\end{cases}
$$
where $0\leq i\leq 2$ and $1\leq j\leq 2$. Counting the $\sigma_{ij}$, we see we have found $6$ automorphisms, so we have found all elements of the Galois group. Since there is no element of order $6$, we know the Galois group is $S_3$. Finally, suppose $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, call it $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, $S_3$ is a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$. Since $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian, this implies $S_3$ is abelian, a contradiction. Hence $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is this correct?

Comment: I’m convinced by what you did!

Comment: I was wondering if cube roots of integers are in cyclotomic fields, and this question answer that. I'm making this comment to to be able to find it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The splitting field is correct and the reasoning seems the right path to take, but notice that in order to affirm that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]5) \not\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ you don't have to put in play $S_{3}$ : If $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]5) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ since Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})/\mathbb{Q}$) is in particolar abelian, every subgroup is normal. Thanks to the fundamental theorem of Galois this condition translates into : every subextension is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]5)$ can't be since is not the splitting field of $x^{3}-5$, infact he's missing $\zeta_{3}$.

Comment: This is much easier, thanks.